# Why my laravel Binding Interfaces To Implementations need composer update,otherwise, it would not worked?

Tags: laravel

When I test laravel Binding Interfaces To Implementations.I got an error.
I think it related to autoload. Could you tell me why? Tell me more detail.
The follow is my step:
I made a Interface:

```
namespace App\Contracts;

interface EventPusherInterface
{
    public function showSelf();
}
```

and implement it

```
namespace App\Services;

use App\Contracts\EventPusherInterface;

class RedisEventPusher implements EventPusherInterface
{
    public function showSelf()
    {
        return 'test contact';
    }
}
```

register in AppServiceProvider

```
$this->app->bind(
    EventPusherInterface::class,
    RedisEventPusher::class
);
```

And ask it in Controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Contracts\EventPusherInterface;
use App\Contracts\InterFaceTestSecond;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TestContactController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @var InterFaceTestSecond
     */
    protected $eventPusher;

    /**
     * TestContactController constructor.
     * @param InterFaceTestSecond $eventPusher
     */
    public function __construct(
        InterFaceTestSecond $eventPusher
    ) {
        $this->eventPusher = $eventPusher;
    }

    public function show()
    {
        dd($this->eventPusher->showSelf());
    }
}
```

Then I got an error

[image]

Then I command `composer update`
It's worked.
I just wonder why???

Answer (score 0):

This is because of how Laravel bootstrap's the application.

If you look at `/vendor/autoload_clasmap.php`, you'll find that all of your classes are mapped there. This makes resolving them as dependencies through the service container possible.

Not all files require that the autoloader is rebuilt, as they are not resolved through the service container. In your case, your interface and inheritance pattern must be resolved through the service container and therefore rely on the `autoload_classmap` to contain a definition for those classes.

Hopefully this clears things up.

Comment: Thank you. So how can i solve it? the document don't tell us config autoload file in this case. Do I need composer update every time when `Binding Interfaces To Implementations`? I think it is not a good idea. If I can config it in someway?

Comment: @Eqer No, you will need to `composer update` everytime.

Comment: I have tested it which show that I need composer update everytime when I create a interface otherwise  I will got an error.